# SystemStatusBar statusItem title being cut short on OS X

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I am trying to display an OS X application statusItem in the System Status Bar and am having success with everything except the fact that the title is being cut off. I am initializing everything like so:

```
let statusItem = NSStatusBar.systemStatusBar().statusItemWithLength(-1)


func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    let icon = NSImage(named: "statusIcon")
    icon?.template = true
    statusItem.image = icon
    statusItem.menu = statusMenu
    statusItem.title = "This is a test title"
}
```

The problem is the `statusItem.title` is appearing like so:
[image]

As you can see the application next to mine (iStatMenuBar) is cutting off the title to my application (or something similar is happening)

If I comment out the icon for the statusItem, it works and shows the entire title but when I re-add the icon it cuts off again. Is there a way for the two (icon and title) to co exist? I have reviewed some Apple docs and may have missed a critical piece which explains this.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to assign a custom view to your statusBarItem and within that view's class override drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) e.g.

```
    private var icon:StatusMenuView?
    let bar = NSStatusBar.systemStatusBar()
    item = bar.statusItemWithLength(-1)

    self.icon = StatusMenuView()
    item!.view = icon
```

and StatusMenuView might look like:

```
    // This is an edited copy & paste from one of my personal projects so it might be missing some code
    class StatusMenuView:NSView {
        private(set) var image: NSImage
       private let titleString:NSString = "really long title..."

        init() {
            icon = NSImage(named: "someImage")!
            let myWideStatusBarItemFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 180.0, NSStatusBar.systemStatusBar().thickness)
            super.init(frame.rect)
        }


        override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect)
        {
            self.item.drawStatusBarBackgroundInRect(dirtyRect, withHighlight: self.isSelected)

            let size = self.image.size
            let rect = CGRectMake(2, 2, size.width, size.height)

            self.image.drawInRect(rect)


            let titleRect = CGRectMake( 2 + size.width, dirtyRect.origin.y, 180.0 - size.width, size.height)
            self.titleString.drawInRect(titleRect, withAttributes: nil)
        }
    }
```

Now, the above might change your event handling, you'll need to handle mouseDown in the StatusMenuView class.